# Laptop keeps booting to GNU GRUB after formatting Ubuntu partition

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-10, partitioning, grub

I formatted my Ubuntu partition, but my computer still boots to GNU GRUB. I tried creating a windows recovery thingy on a USB stick and using bootrec.exe /fixmbr and variants thereof, all of which said "Operation completed successfully", but I'm still booting to GNU GRUB. Is there a different command I need to use?

I'm using Windows 10.

Windows is available if I can get to the boot selection and it boots fine, but I want to uninstall Ubuntu completely.

Alternatively; I deleted Ubuntu because I wanted to downgrade to 15.04. If I installed Ubuntu again, would it break anything or would the boot boot me into Ubuntu instead of GRUB? It seems risky which is why I haven't tried.

EDIT: important note: I'm booting to GRUB, not GRUB rescue.

Answer (score 0):

the same happened to me
what I did was using a live Linux CD to backup all my data from my hard drive and do a fresh clean to my hard desk
then I installed windows again

Comment: Your answer may be right but you presentation is downright horrible. Please try to present your answer in a more *understandable* manner.

Answer (score 0):

I like @user598790 's answer. You might also try a bootable Linux flashdrive with boot-repair. 
Or just do a re-install of 15.04 and see if it cleans up grub.

The problem, I suspect, is that you formatted away the grub files on the linux partition, but the grub files on the EFI boot sector are still there with nothing to point to.